# Underground surface3d be Dark

Tags: qt, qml

I wanna show a surface3d in qml by one serie , but i need one property that show under surface3d in dark mode.

**under surface3d fill by dark color** .
(i dont want use one more serie for taking it in dark, i mean some property like an image or better way that has good performance, because i updating surface in seconds and its not good to use one more serie that depending my own serie.)

[surface3d](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/149513/Imported_Blog_Media/Surface-example_017-2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used multiSeries and solved .
but i wanted another way to solve it , like an image texture under surface.